# make variable from struts 2 available in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to set the css of an element conditionally. This is the line in the jsp:

```
<s:textfield name="registerBean.email" placeholder="Email Address*" cssClass="INSERT userNameError here" required="" />
<s:textfield name="registerBean.userName" placeholder="Username*" cssClass="INSERT emailError here" required="" />
```

In my action class i have something like this:

```
package actions;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import service.implementations.UserServiceImplementation;
import service.interfaces.UserService;
import util.REGISTER_RESULT;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import entities.User;

public class Register extends ActionSupport {

    private User registerBean;
    private String userNameError = "register";
    private String emailError = "register";

    @Override
    public String execute()
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ExamModulePu");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        UserService service = new UserServiceImplementation(em);
        REGISTER_RESULT result = service.registerUser(registerBean);


        if(result.isDuplicateEmail())
            setEmailError("register error");
        if(result.isDuplicateUserName())
            setUserNameError("register error");
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return result.toString();
    }

    public User getRegisterBean() {
        return registerBean;
    }

    public void setRegisterBean(User registerBean) {
        this.registerBean = registerBean;
    }

    public String getEmailError() {
        return emailError;
    }

    public void setEmailError(String emailError) {
        this.emailError = emailError;
    }

    public String getUserNameError() {
        return userNameError;
    }

    public void setUserNameError(String userNameError) {
        this.userNameError = userNameError;
    }
}
```

How can i go about making these variables available to the jsp? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For giving some CSS class to validation failed fields you can use `cssErrorClass` attribute.

```
<s:textfield name="registerBean.userName" placeholder="Username*" cssErrorClass="register error" required="" />
```

And in your action use `addFieldError` method to add error to specific field.

Comment: No idea struts2 was that powerful. Know of any place where i can learn cool stuff like this? Thanks